# Error: index_not_found_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I use ELK stack to analyze my log file. I have tested last week and everything works well.

Today, I tested but I get this error when I typed "http://localhost:9200/iot_log/_count" (iot_log is my index pattern):

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no
>   such
>   index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"iot_log","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"iot_log"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such
>   index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"iot_log","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"iot_log"},"status":404}

I really searched the forums but I have not found a solution, I want to know what is the cause of this problem please and how can I correct it?

Comment: Can you show the output you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices/` ?

Comment: Thank you for your return. When I tried your command line I get this:  
yellow open .kibana aC1e9PoVQBGNGjW0CbmdsA 1 1 6 0 34.7kb 34.7kb

Comment: Then it means you have a single index called `.kibana` and nothing else, so something or someone has deleted all other indices, or you're not hitting the correct ES cluster.

Comment: I tried to change the filter (add a variable) and then I got this error. Then, I tried to remove logstash-5.1.1 and re install it again but I still have the same error, so have you an idea please how can I correct it? What should I do?

Comment: Not sure what to say, except that your ES cluster is completely empty according to the info you provided...

Comment: I used the same configuration file and the same template json file that I used last week and they worked well, so should I uninstall (elasticsearch, logstash and kibana) and reinstall them or what should I do please? I am a beginner and really I need a solution.

Comment: I don't know what was done in the meantime and was deleted your indices, so you need to figure that out first.

Answer (score 31):

Make sure index iot_log exist and [create it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) if not:

`curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/iot_log" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "settings" : { "index" : { } }}'`

Comment: just to make it clear, this will create an `index` named `iot_log`, so we can change `iot_log` to whatever we want.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set your `action.auto_create_index` parameter in `elasticsearch.yml` file.

Example:

```
action.auto_create_index: -l*,+z*
```

With this kind of configuration, indexes starting with "z" will be created automatically while indexes starting with "l" will not.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to resolve it by using setting as follow

Allow Auto Create YourIndexName and index10 and not allowing any index name matching index1* and any other index matching ind*. The patterns are matched in the order they are given.

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
    "persistent": {
        "action.auto_create_index": "YourIndexName,index10,-index1*,+ind*" 
    }
}'
```

Stop any Auto Indexing

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
    "persistent": {
        "action.auto_create_index": "false" 
    }
}'
```

Allow any Index create automatically

````
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
    "persistent": {
        "action.auto_create_index": "true" 
    }
}'
```
````

Answer (score 0):

In my case, My all data is **DELETED** in elastic search automatically, After importing data again in elastic search my application working good.

Comment: i've had same issue all the docs were deleted apparently one at a time and then the index itself