# Elasticsearch Missing404Exception in Connection.php#602

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I'm running a Laravel application & Elasticsearch5.5

When accessing ES on the application I get following error:

Log file:

```
[2019-02-22 09:43:24] local.ERROR: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"ah_index_dev2_en","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"ah_index_dev2_en"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"ah_index_dev2_en","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"ah_index_dev2_en"},"status":404} {"userId":2359,"email":"steven.gerrits.94@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\Missing404Exception(code: 404): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"index_not_found_exception\",\"reason\":\"no such index\",\"resource.type\":\"index_or_alias\",\"resource.id\":\"ah_index_dev2_en\",\"index_uuid\":\"_na_\",\"index\":\"ah_index_dev2_en\"}],\"type\":\"index_not_found_exception\",\"reason\":\"no such index\",\"resource.type\":\"index_or_alias\",\"resource.id\":\"ah_index_dev2_en\",\"index_uuid\":\"_na_\",\"index\":\"ah_index_dev2_en\"},\"status\":404} at /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:602)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(273): Elasticsearch\\Connections\\Connection->process4xxError(Array, Array, Array)
#1 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(25): Elasticsearch\\Connections\\Connection->Elasticsearch\\Connections\\{closure}(Array)
#2 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\\Promise\\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#3 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Core.php(341): GuzzleHttp\\Ring\\Future\\CompletedFutureValue->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#4 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(294): GuzzleHttp\\Ring\\Core::proxy(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Ring\\Future\\CompletedFutureArray), Object(Closure))
#5 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(171): Elasticsearch\\Connections\\Connection->Elasticsearch\\Connections\\{closure}(Array, Object(Elasticsearch\\Connections\\Connection), Object(Elasticsearch\\Transport), Array)
#6 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php(106): Elasticsearch\\Connections\\Connection->performRequest('GET', '/ah_index_dev2_...', Array, '{\"query\":{\"quer...', Array, Object(Elasticsearch\\Transport))
#7 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php(1578): Elasticsearch\\Transport->performRequest('GET', '/ah_index_dev2_...', Array, Array, Array)
#8 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php(952): Elasticsearch\\Client->performRequest(Object(Elasticsearch\\Endpoints\\Search))
#9 [internal function]: Elasticsearch\\Client->search(Array)
#10 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch/src/Manager.php(133): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(221): Cviebrock\\LaravelElasticsearch\\Manager->__call('search', Array)
#12 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/app/Service/ElasticSearchService.php(450): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('search', Array)
#13 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php(556): App\\Service\\ElasticSearchService->simpleSearch()
#14 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php(434): App\\Http\\Controllers\\SearchController->doSearch()
#15 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\SearchController->horseSearch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), NULL, 'horse')
#16 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('horseSearch', Array)
#18 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller->callAction('horseSearch', Array)
#19 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(212): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\SearchController), 'horseSearch')
#20 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(169): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#21 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#22 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/app/Http/Middleware/Language.php(36): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): App\\Http\\Middleware\\Language->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/app/Http/Middleware/LanguageSetting.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): App\\Http\\Middleware\\LanguageSetting->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(68): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(660): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#49 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(601): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#51 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(590): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#54 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(65): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#56 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#57 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#58 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#59 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#60 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#62 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#63 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#64 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#65 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#66 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#67 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#68 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#69 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#70 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#71 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#72 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#73 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#74 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#75 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#76 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/server.php(21): require_once('/Users/stevenge...')
#77 {main}
"}
```

I did research & found this thread:

[Errors upon searching in Elasticsearch using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370448/errors-upon-searching-in-elasticsearch-using-php)

So I checked if my ES is running. When running with "./bin/elasticsearch" I get following answer which it's running, ok?

```
[2019-02-22T09:00:11,578][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2019-02-22T09:00:11,647][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [EqUb7-7] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/disk1s1)]], net usable_space [193.1gb], net total_space [233.4gb], spins? [unknown], types [apfs]
[2019-02-22T09:00:11,647][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [EqUb7-7] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2019-02-22T09:00:11,648][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [EqUb7-7] derived from node ID [EqUb7-7fR3er1V_1KbKyiA]; set [node.name] to override
[2019-02-22T09:00:11,648][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.5.0], pid[36077], build[260387d/2017-06-30T23:16:05.735Z], OS[Mac OS X/10.14.2/x86_64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.2/11.0.2+9-LTS]
[2019-02-22T09:00:11,649][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] JVM arguments [-Xms2g, -Xmx2g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+DisableExplicitGC, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.path.home=/users/stevengerrits/elasticsearch-5.5.0]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,258][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [parent-join]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,258][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [percolator]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,258][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [reindex]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,258][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,258][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2019-02-22T09:00:12,258][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [EqUb7-7] no plugins loaded
[2019-02-22T09:00:13,441][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [EqUb7-7] using discovery type [zen]
[2019-02-22T09:00:13,804][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2019-02-22T09:00:13,804][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [EqUb7-7] starting ...
[2019-02-22T09:00:13,989][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [EqUb7-7] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9300}, {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2019-02-22T09:00:17,056][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [EqUb7-7] new_master {EqUb7-7}{EqUb7-7fR3er1V_1KbKyiA}{SLRzB7PtSUyeI8J7hwMnWQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2019-02-22T09:00:17,083][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [EqUb7-7] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9200}, {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2019-02-22T09:00:17,083][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [EqUb7-7] started
[2019-02-22T09:00:17,101][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [EqUb7-7] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

doing a `curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'`
gives:

```
   {
  "name" : "Hfe5NY6",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "jDUNRES3SuC5bhUesVpNnw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.0",
    "build_hash" : "780f8c4",
    "build_date" : "2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: According to the error message, you have no index called `ah_index_dev2_en`

Comment: I'm new in laravel.. where does i have to index that?

Comment: Maybe show us some bit of code

Comment: It's a large project, which files are relevant? database name is ah_index_dev2 and we are using en and de for switching languages, maybe that could help..

Comment: @Val when I access the page with DE language, it works! You know where to index that language? sorry, i'm very new in laravel

Comment: @Val Could the problem be: I installed ES5.5 locally and I run the server via my terminal. In Laravel I installed it via composer require cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch:^2

But that supports ESv5.4. 
How can I connect my laravel application to the ES I installed via the terminal?

Comment: @Val I stopped my ES5.5 server, installed the 5.4 and started it. Re-run my project, but still got the same error..

Comment: THis thread helped me to solve my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804863/error-index-not-found-exception

Comment: For other people with this issue, might want to have a look at [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/per_request_configuration.html#_ignoring_exceptions)